# Image jumps down on Google Chrome Browser on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, submit

The below code works perfectly, however, in Chrome the image which is in the class "platters-basket-update-button" moves down a few pixels when the button is clicked. It doesn't move again until the page is refreshed?

```
<div class="menu-two-column-product-main-cell-right-button-plus plus">
 <a class="formqtyplus plus">+</a>
</div>
<div class="new-qty-box-update">
 <input name="update" value="" type="submit" class="platters-basket-update-button">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".input a").click(function () {
var inputEl = $(this).parent().parent().children().next().children();
var qty = inputEl.val();
if ($(this).parent().hasClass("plus"))
qty++;
else
qty--;
if (qty < 0)
qty = 1;
inputEl.val(qty);
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding **return false** on the click() function?

http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/rh4Bw/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input a").click(function () {
        var inputEl = $(this).parent().parent().children().next().children();
        var qty = inputEl.val();
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("plus"))
        qty++;
        else
        qty--;
        if (qty < 0)
        qty = 1;
        inputEl.val(qty);


        return false;       //Prevents the "JUMP" on browser
    })
});
```